# Does a rotating disk produce a DC current

Tags: electromagnetism

My problem comes from this thread: [Does a rotating disk develop a potential difference between the centre and rim?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188515/does-a-rotating-disk-develop-a-potential-difference-between-the-centre-and-rim)

My issue is that I don't see why the assumption of equilibrium commented by Cag must be done. I mean: how do we know that we should expect the electrons to be in equilibrium? Isn't it possible that a steady state current is produced by the electrons which are thrown away from the disk by the centrifugal force? I know that the drag forces in the case of an applied electric field lead the electrons to move really slowly due to the collisions with the metal lattice, but still I don't see why a current is impossible to be produced.

Another question that I make to myself (and to you) is the following: is the electric force produced by the center of the disk at the rim stronger along the disk itself or along the conducting wire? If the answer to the second question is positive, the electrons might jump the potential barrier at the rim and a DC current might be set up.

I must admit that this problem has troubled me since long, because I still see holes in the answers I find.

Comment: If the disk is in a magnetic field? Yes. That's called a homopolar generator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_generator. You can try it yourself at home with an electric drill, a flat metal disk, a magnet, a couple of wires and a simple voltmeter. It's kind of a cute and simple experiment. Why does it work? Because a charge moving in a magnetic field experiences an electric field. Relativity at home!

Comment: Please make the second question more clear. I cannot make any sense out of "is the electric force produced by the center of the disk at the rim stronger along the disk itself or along the conducting wire?".

Answer (score 1):

There will be an equilibrium and no steady state current which keeps generating. The reason is that after some of the electrons get deposited on the rim, then they give rise to an electrostatic potential difference between the rim and the centre, the centre having a positive potential due to the loss of electrons, while the rim having a negative potential due to excess electrons. The force due to this potential difference is opposite to the direction of motion of moving electrons and repels the further flow of electrons happening from the centre to the rim and after the potential difference becomes sufficiently high further motion of electrons is stopped and thus an equilibrium is reached where electrons do not further move towards the rim.

Comment: Excuse me for the ambiguity in my second question. What I meant is the following: I can understand that the total force will be zero after a certain distribution of negative charge will be accumulated on the rim. However, a null force still enables electrons to move at constant speed from the rim to the center of the disk and from there to the rim again, closing the cycle. However, it seems this is not possible, so a DC current cannot exist. Why?

Comment: zero force won't allow an electron to keep moving with some constant speed as its kinetic energy would decrease to zero after collisions with atoms in its path. So a null force won't allow a steady state current.

Comment: I neglected the collisions with the metal lattice, but we can add these interactions to the problem: in this case, why are we sure that the centrifugal force will always compensate the repulsion from the electrons on the rim?

Comment: @Eden because if centrifugal force is lesser than the force due to electrons at the rim, then they would never have been there at the first place. If it is more than the force at the rim, then similarly they will go on and deposit at the rim. If they are equal, then they have reached equilibrium and that is why no further current will flow.

Comment: Therefore, why doesn't the same occur when a magnetic field is present? A certain amount of electrons will also accumulate at the rim, right? Let's say, if the total force is non-zero (dragging + centrifugal + rim) and at the beginning of the motion this is necessary non-zero, how do you know that at certain moment the electrons will not move anymore? Sorry, I don't say you aren't right, but I don't see the point of your reasoning. A net zero force doesn't imply non-existence of motion!

Comment: @Eden a ball on a flat horizontal surface has no horizontal forces acting on it...so either it can roll or it can rest..if it is rolling, then frictional forces cause it to stop..that's it...same goes for the electrons...if the electrons are moving when the forces balance out to be 0, then they would encounter collisions with atoms/other electrons which play the role of what friction does to a ball..now you say that a steady state current is generated due to centrifugal force with collisions, right...then the steady state current deposits even more charge of the similar kind on the rim.....

Comment: and the centre and that will produce a force on the free electrons in the rod in the direction opposite to their motion and will infact give rise to a current opposite to their motion..these opposite currents give a net average velocity of 0 to the electrons...just try to think deeply about the problem.. also see the reasoning behind a depletion layer in a p-n junction, it might be helpful..

Comment: also you said something about why a steady current is produced in a magnetic field, right?? ok the answer is it doesn't until the rim and the centre are connected, otherwise a potential is developed between them which prevents further instances of steady state current.. A net zero force doesn't imply non-existence of motion but you need to understand what forces are actually at work first... in this case, you are wrong and i don't see the point of your reasoning !! And the next time you post a question do make it clear what you are looking for and try to understand what others are saying...

Comment: A ball on a flat horizontal surface initially moving will indeed stop due to the friction if there isn't any other force. But the case of the electrons in the rotating disk is different: I imagine the ball pushed by a force produced by your hand (in the case of the disk, the centrifugal force) and the friction acts as a force in the opposite direction. You can also add the repulsive force from the electrons on the rim. But the total force might be zero and still exist motion. But if you are convinced I'm wrong, I believe it isn't worth to continue the discussion. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: my last three comments described exactly this situation in clear terms. re-read them..

Comment: @BruceLee  you're clearly correct that no steady state current would flow; however, I would fully expect a potential difference to develop between the rim and center of rotation, held by the inertial forces of the free charges. While I wouldn't expect it to be large, it should be measurable to two non rotating contacts placed at the indicated positions. In that sense a current might be generated similarly to a homopolar genrator